# How density function of chi-squared has been found ? By who?

Tags: density-estimation, chi-squared-distribution, history

I want to understand **how the chi-squared cumulative distribution function has been found**.

By who? Pearson? Other?

I search to compute it without using formula found on the Web at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) but in using only integral and probability rules.

As a reminder, the chi-squared density function is

$$
{\displaystyle f_{X}(x;k)={\frac {1}{2^{\frac {k}{2}}\Gamma ({\frac {k}{2}})}}x^{{\frac {k}{2}}-1}e^{-{\frac {x}{2}}}\,}
$$

How was this function found?

How this function can be simulated using only integral and probability rules ?

Comment: Doesn't Section 8 of the Wikipedia entry that you have cited answer the question about who discovered the chi-square distribution?

Comment: You are right. The author of this formula seems to be Helmert. But Pearson seems having discovered the same thing a little later. I have looked at reference and I have found some explanation from Helmert himself in his "book Ueber die Wahrscheinlichkeit der Potenzsummen der Beobachtungsfehler und über einige damit im Zusammenhange stehende Fragen" written in 'old' german. Is there a document in english ? What has Pearson written about this ?